# Sort array of objects alphabetically and move the empty values to the end

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort the array by `lname` in ascending order and by moving empty values to the end.

I am able to sort in ascending order, but how to move empty values to last?

```js
let arr = [{
  name: 'z',
  lname: 'first'
}, {
  name: 'y',
  lname: ''
}, {
  name: 'a',
  lname: 'third'
}]

const copy = [...arr];

copy.sort((a, b) => (a.lname > b.lname ? 1 : -1))

console.log(copy);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: have some logic in your sort callback that tests if lname is blank and return appropriate values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a separate expression for when a string is empty:

```
copy.sort((a, b)=> !a.lname - !b.lname || a.lname.localeCompare(b.lname));
```

Note that among strings (only) an empty string is falsy, so applying `!` to it will give true when that is the case. Subtracting two booleans will turn those values into 0 (for false) and 1 (for true).<sup>*</sup> `!a.lname - !b.lname` will be negative when only `b.lname` is empty. It will be positive when only `a.lname` is empty. In all other cases, the comparison will be done with `localeCompare`.

---

<sub>* TypeScript complains about this type mismatch; in that case convert the boolean values to number explicitly with the unary plus operator: `+!a.lname - +!b.name`</sub>

Comment: you should convert it first to lower case when comparing them `a.lname.toLowerCase.localeCompare` same for b

Comment: @lfaruki, the OP did not say anything about case sensitivity. Their code does not use `toLowerCase`, nor do they say they want it. Their question is about the empty strings.